# vtkOBJReader import OBJ as individual vtkPolyData objects

Tags: python-3.x, vtk, vtk.js

My intention is to get the vtkPolyData(*ideally colored/textured via the vtk OBJ import*) to pass to k3d viewer using;

```
k3d.vtk_poly_data(<vtkPolyData>)
```

vtkGLTFReader gives a vtkMultiBlock that which can be easily iterated over to get access to multiple vtkPolyData objects as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63130386/rendering-a-gltf-glb-file-in-jupyter-notebook-using-vtk-and-k3d/63130387#63130387)?

vtkOBJReader on the other hand returns a vtkPolyData object that encompasses all the objects in one obj. So I have lost my reference to individual objects and their guids/ids;

```
reader = vtk.vtkOBJReader() 
reader.SetFileName('Sample.obj')
reader.Update() 
vtkPolyData = reader.GetOutput() #Problem! all .OBJ elements in one vtkPolyData instance
```

1. Is it possible to get access to the individual vtkPolyData objects
   from the .OBJ without splitting the .OBJ in multiple files?
2. Is a vtkMultiBlock version of the data accessible from the vtk python
   module? Or is this only possible via js version of vtk as described [here](https://discourse.paraview.org/t/how-to-set-groupids-c1-in-object-obj-file/1946/3)

Since the vtkImporter class supersedes vtkReader class and already correctly displays objects with material (.mtl) I suspect there is a way to get access the geometry through the Render_Window object, but I could not manage this.

**SOLUTION**;

```
importer = vtk.vtkOBJImporter()
importer.SetFileName('Sample.obj')
importer.SetFileNameMTL('Sample.mtl')

#preview with material using the importer
importer.Read()
importer.InitializeObjectBase()
importer.GetRenderer()
vtkRenderWindowInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
Render_Window = importer.GetRenderWindow()
vtkRenderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(Render_Window)

actors = Renderer.GetActors()
actors.InitTraversal() #Unpacks OBJ !

#Iterate over actors to get PolyData!
pds = []
for a in range(actors.GetNumberOfItems()):
    actor = actors.GetNextActor()

    # OBJImporter turns texture interpolation off
    if actor.GetTexture():
        actor.GetTexture().InterpolateOn()

    pd = actor.GetMapper().GetInput()
    
    #mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper(actor.GetMapper()) #Throws TypeError: Method requires a string argument!
    mapper = actor.GetMapper() #use this in python
    mapper.SetInputData(pd)
    pds.append(pd)

vtkRenderWindowInteractor.Start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking in the right direction wiht the importer and the renderer.
The renderer object contains actors, each one has a mapper that contains a polydata as input.

See this cxx example (python API is the same, except you can directly iterate through `renderer.GetActors()`): https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/IO/OBJImporter/

Comment: Thanks for the example. That did the trick for getting the vtkPolyData as separate items!  I updated the Question with the python Solution to it. However this line throws an error asking for a String Argument instead of a PolyDataMapper object;
`mapper = 
    vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper(actor.GetMapper())`
I can get the pds by ommiting this part. What is the mapper actually doing here? Is it assigning colors/textures/appended data of the .OBJ to the vtkpolydata object?

Comment: sorry, in python you just need `mapper  = actor.GetMapper()`

Comment: Ok Great. What is it actually adding the vtkpolydata obj? Currently I have some data's and colors I would like to carry over to K3D Viewer objects, I was thinking that this is what the mapper is for.

Comment: The mapper is indeed here to manage polydata color. But I don't know about K3D API. May be it should be better to open a new thread about VTK to K3D ?