# vtkOBJImporter id to k3D

Tags: python-3.x, vtk, vtk.js

How does one access the (g) ID of the obj from the k3d scene objects which I have passed from vtkOBJImporter using the method outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63813140/11016602).

(g) should be the group name. However I could't find documentation of vtk of where the group name is stored once it is imported by vtkOBJImporter.

.OBJ
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the current source code (https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/blob/master/IO/Import/vtkOBJImporter.cxx#L275), it seems the `g`  type is not handle by the `vtkOBJImporter`.

Feel free to open a feature request ([https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/issues/new?issue[assignee_id]=&issue[milestone_id]=](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/issues/new?issue%5Bassignee_id%5D=&issue%5Bmilestone_id%5D=)). Or even a merge request :)

Comment: Thanks. I opened a feature request here: https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/issues/18011

Is the "name" tag in glb files handled by the vtkGLTFImporter? I am asking because this could be a suitable secondary alternative handle to access the GUIDS of ifc files converted to OBJ or GLB via ifcCovert http://ifcopenshell.org/ifcconvert

Also in both cases is this information stored with the vtkPolydataObject as a vtkInformation entry or as vtkFieldData?