# vtkOBJImporter color mapping for k3d

Tags: python-3.x, vtk, vtk.js

Following the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63813140/11016602), one can get granular vtkPolyData to pass to k3d in python. However I am currently assigning color to k3d like so;

```
def rgb2hex(r,g,b):
     return eval("0x{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}".format(r,g,b))

#using the actors from [referenced code][1] to get the granular actors from .OBJ
col = actor.GetProperty().GetDiffuseColor()
rgb2hex(int(col[0]*255),int(col[1]*255),int(col[2]*255))
```

This is ugly and inefficient. vtkPolyDataMapper should be already handling the color, so there must be a way of doing this in a more direct way. How can one use the vtkPolyDataMapper to get a list of colors to pipe to the k3d.vtk_poly_data() color argument?

```
mapper = actor.GetMapper() 
mapper.SetInputData(vtkPolyData)
```

Comment: I don't know about k3d. Can you be more precise please? Do you want one color per polydata ? In wich format ?

Comment: Yes, one color per polydata. I need to do this for multiple (100s) of polydata's so I am wondering if there is a direct way to access the color data in the format needed (shown in the eval() function, like so  "0x{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}".format(r,g,b). k3d documentation for relevant function;
https://k3d-jupyter.org/k3d.html?highlight=vtk#k3d.factory.vtk_poly_data

Answer (score 1):

VTK does not natively provide this formatting (`0xrrggbb`) for color. You always have to deal with 3-components floats or integers.